# Solution Verification: Finding Values of a probability function in this question.

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-variables

Here's the question:

> Sam wants to get all the collection of $4$ different toys that can be optained by opening surprise boxes, in every box he opens theres a random toy from the $4$ toys (with an equal probability to appear for every one of the $4$ toys), and all the surprise boxes are independent. 
> Let $X$ be the number of surprise boxes sam needs to open in order to get all the $4$ toys. 
> Find the probability function of $x$ for every $x<7$.

**My Work**: 
So every toy has probability of $\frac {1}{4}$ to appear in every box. and basically I need to find $P(X=x)$ for every $x\in \{4,5,6\}$ since we need to open atleast $4$ boxes to get the $4$ toys. 

$P(X=4)=P(\text {He Got 4 Different Toys In A row})=(\frac{1}{4})^4*4!=\frac{3}{32}$.
$P(X=5)=P(\text {He Got Same Toy Twice Before Getting All 4})=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{4}*\frac{5!}{2!}=\frac{45}{256}.$ ($5!$ ordering them all and dividing by the number of orders we can put the Two same toy in). 
$P(X=6)=P(\text {2 Toys Appear Twice Each Or 1 Toy Appears 3 Times})=(\frac{1}{4})^4* \frac{3}{4}* \frac{2}{4}*\frac{6!}{2!2!}+(\frac{1}{4})^3* \frac{3}{4} *(\frac{1}{4})^2*\frac{6!}{5!}=\frac{135}{512}+\frac{45}{512}=\frac{180}{512}$

Would love to hear feedback about mistakes that I made, or an approval if my solution seems ok, any help and comment is appreciated!

Comment: If you want to write plaintext in a MathJax block, enclose it in ```\text{ [your text] }```.

Comment: @Lt.Commander.Data Thanks for letting me know I was struggling with it, edited the question :).

Comment: I get $P(X=5) = 9/64$ by a branching tree method.

Comment: And $P(X=6) = 3/32$.  I'll try the problem another way to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a branching tree method:

I branch on whether a new toy was found or not, to keep the number of branches short.

For $P(X=4)$, we get one toy, then a $3/4$ chance of getting a different toy, then a $1/2$ chance of a new one, then a $1/4$ chance, for $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{6}{64} = \frac{3}{32}$.

For $P(X=5)$, there are three ways it can happen: failing to get a new toy on the second, third, or fourth draw only.

$$P(X=5) = 3/4*1/2*3/4*1/4 + 3/4*1/2*1/2*1/4 + 1/4*3/4*1/2*1/4 = 9/64$$

For $P(X=6)$, there are six ways it can happen, giving $\frac{75}{512}$ overall.

Alternate approach:  **Inclusion-Exclusion Principle**

The idea is to find the probability of failing to get all four kinds.  Suppose the toys are $A,B,C,$ and $D$.  The probability of never getting toy $D$ is $\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^4$, and there are four choices of toy.  However, that overcounts because of the possibility of failing to get two of the toys, which is similarly $\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^4$, and there are six choices of $2$ toys to not get.  Subtracting that, we are undercounting again, because of the possibility of only getting one kind of toy getting subtracted out and so we have to add it back in: $\big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^4$, which can happen $4$ ways.

So finally we have $P(X>4) = \frac{58}{64}$, so $P(X=4) = \frac{6}{64}$.

For $P(X>5)$ I get $\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^5 \cdot 4 - \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^5 \cdot 6 + \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^4 \cdot 4 = \frac{243}{256} - \frac{6}{32} + \frac{1}{256} = \frac{49}{64}$, so $P(X\leq 5) = \frac{15}{64}$, and since $P(X=4) = \frac{6}{64}$, we get $P(X=5) = \frac{15}{64} - \frac{6}{64} = \frac{9}{64}$ which matches the first method.

For $P(X>6)$ I get $$\big(\frac{3}{4}\big)^6*4 - \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^6*6 + \big(\frac{1}{4}\big)^6*4 = \frac{317}{512}$$ which means $P(X\leq 6) = \frac{195}{512}$ and subtracting $P(X\leq 5) = \frac{15}{64}$ I get $P(X=6) = \frac{75}{512}$, which matches (once I fixed an arithmetic error in the first method!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I appreciate it alot, I understood all the first part, I tried to understand your calculations using the inclusion exclusion principle but I didn't quite get it, I would be happy if you can add a little explanation of how you thought of the calculations like $(\frac{3}{4})^4$ ..

Comment: I edited to spell it out a bit more. Basically since there is a $(3/4)^4$ chance of not getting any $D$'s, that is $81/256$, but if you count that four times, you actually get $81/64$ for the probability, which makes it obvious that we overcounted. We double counted those cases that got no $C$'s AND no $D$'s, for example.  So we subtract those, but then we subtracted too much because of the "got only $A$'s" option etc.